# How do you check to see if input is numerical, and if it's not, ask for one?

Tags: java, parsing, numbers

**EDIT: None of the answers so far work. The closest I've gotten (Thank you, TNT) is using:**

```
while (true) {
    try {
        value = s.nextDouble();
        break;
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("That is not a number! Please enter a numerical value.");
    }
}
```

**but if the user inputs something like "foo", it puts me in an infinite loop saying "That is not a number! Please enter a numerical value."**

My program here asks for an unit to choose from (fl.oz, gal, oz, lb, in, ft, or mi), asks how much of it they have, and asks for the unit they wish to convert to (mL, l, g, kg, mm, cm, m, or km).

My program works, refusing to convert from silly conversions such as gal to cm, telling you to re-input if they enter anything other than fl.oz, gal, etc.

The only thing I cannot figure out is if the user inputs something like "foo" when the program prompts the user for how much of the unit they have. My goal is to have the program say something like "That is not a number! Please enter a numerical value." If I run the program currently and enter anything but a numerical value, I get errors in the console. I'm pretty sure there is going to be loops involved, and I've looked up the API documentation for parse, but I'm  still stuck.

Here is my program (it's long, sorry!):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UnitConversions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What kind of unit do you have? Choose from: fl.oz, gal, oz, lb, in, ft, or mi. ");
        String startingVariable = s.next();

        while (!startingVariable.equals("fl.oz") && !startingVariable.equals("gal") && !startingVariable.equals("oz")
                && !startingVariable.equals("lb") && !startingVariable.equals("in") && !startingVariable.equals("ft") &&
                !startingVariable.equals("mi")) {
            System.out.println("That is not what I asked. Please choose from: fl.oz, gal, oz, lb, in, ft, or mi. ");
            startingVariable = s.next();
        }

        System.out.println("How much of it do you have? ");
        double value = s.nextDouble();
        //here, I don't know what to put!

        System.out.println("What would you like to convert to? Choose from: mL, l, g, kg, mm, cm, m, or km ");
        String convertedVariable = s.next();

        while (!convertedVariable.equals("mL") && !convertedVariable.equals("l") && !convertedVariable.equals("g")
                && !convertedVariable.equals("kg") && !convertedVariable.equals("mm") && !convertedVariable.equals("cm") &&
                !convertedVariable.equals("m") && !convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
            System.out.println("That is not what I asked. Please choose from: mL, l, g, kg, mm, cm, m, or km. ");
            convertedVariable = s.next();
        }

        double result = 0;



        if (startingVariable.equals("fl.oz")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = (29.5735 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = (0.0295735 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = 0;
            }
            if (result == 0) {
                System.out.println("You cannot convert from " + startingVariable + " to " + convertedVariable + ".");
                System.out.println("]:");
            }
        }

        if (startingVariable.equals("gal")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = (3785.41 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = (3.78541 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = 0;
            }
        }

        if (startingVariable.equals("oz")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = (29.5735 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = (0.0295735 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = (28.3495 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = (0.0283495 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = 0;
            }
        }

        if (startingVariable.equals("lb")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = (453.592 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = (0.453592 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = 0;
            }
        }

        if (startingVariable.equals("in")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = (25.4 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = (2.54 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = (0.0254 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = (0.000025400 * value);
            }
        }

        if (startingVariable.equals("ft")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = (304.8 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = (30.48 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = (0.30481 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = (0.0003048 * value);
            }
        }

        if (startingVariable.equals("mi")) {
            if (convertedVariable.equals("mL")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("l")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("g")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("kg")) {
                result = 0;
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("mm")) {
                result = (1609344 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("cm")) {
                result = (160934 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("m")) {
                result = (1609.34 * value);
            } else if (convertedVariable.equals("km")) {
                result = (1.60934 * value);
            }
        }

        if (result == 0) {
            System.out.println("You cannot convert from " + startingVariable + " to " + convertedVariable + ". Sorry dude.");
            System.out.println("]:");
        } else {
            System.out.println("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░");
            System.out.printf(value + " " + startingVariable + " =  %.3f " + convertedVariable + ".\n", result);
            System.out.println("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░");
        }
        if (result > 10000) {
            System.out.println("That's a lot of "  + convertedVariable +"!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop and try-catch for a situation like this. As long as something other than a `double` is entered, an `InputMismatchException` will be thrown, so the `break` statement will never be reached unless the user enters a number.

```
double value;
while (true) {
    try {
        value = s.nextDouble();
        break;
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("That is not a number! Please enter a numerical value.");
        s.nextLine();
    }
}
s.nextLine();
```

The reason why it was in an infinite loop before was because the scanner continued attempting to parse the invalid input in the case that the user did not enter a number. The string kept causing an `InputMismatchException` to be thrown, which explains the infinite loop. Adding `s.nextLine()` consumes the invalid input and prevents this from happening. In the event that the user does enter a number, the `s.nextLine()` statement would consume the input so the user will be prompted to enter the next string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the errors are along the lines of a conversion error? You need to catch the exception in a try block and you can then alert the user and get another input.

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch the exception:

```
try 
{
    double value = s.nextDouble();
}
catch(InputMismatchException exception)
{
   System.out.println("This is not a number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the try catch to handle this kind of situation.

when the user input non-numeric it will throw an exception then catch it then perform any thing you want from the catch block.

```
    try{
    System.out.println("How much of it do you have? ");
    double value = s.nextDouble();
    }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
    System.out.println("This is not a number");
    }
```

> public class InputMismatchException extends NoSuchElementException
>
> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

"but if the user inputs something like "foo", it puts me in an infinite loop saying "That is not a number! Please enter a numerical value.""

It does not "put you in an infinite loop", it just keeps asking until you enter a number, like you asked in the original question. What would you like it to do instead?